# Aligning string with spaces

Tags: c#

Is there a way to perfectly align two strings in C#?
I am trying to align the string "CBI" with "Central Bureau of Investigation" and I want both strings to occupy 35 characters. I use the function

```
string.Format("{0,-35}", str);
```

to format both strings. But they do not appear to be aligned properly. Does it have something to do with the font settings?
I have to use these strings in a chart in excel and they have to occupy the same width on the screen

Comment: By "align" do you mean "same width in pixels"? Just because two strings have the same number of characters doesn't mean they'll be the same width on screen.

Comment: For font settings, yes, the font needs to be a fixed width font like `Courier New`

Comment: I agree Bob, my answer only reflects the requirement "I want both strings to occupy 35 characters"

Comment: Yes. PadRight works exactly like string.Format I need a way for it to have same width in Pixels.

Comment: As @RobertByrne mentioned, you need to control the font to achieve this. Use a mono-spaced font and your problems will go away; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) and [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx)

```
str.PadLeft(35);
str.PadRight(35);

str = "BBQ and Slaw";
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(15));  // Displays "   BBQ and Slaw".
Console.Write(str.PadRight(15));     // Displays "BBQ and Slaw   ".
```

Side Note from documentation:

> However, if totalWidth is less than the length of this instance, the method returns a reference to the existing instance

Basically if your length is less than the length of the string then an reference of the existing string is returned

---

If EvenMcDonnal wishes to include this in an answer I'll gladly remove it from my answer.

You can find a list of MonoSpaced fonts you can use [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces)

Comment: Just add 1 more thing and you'll be good: How it appears on the OUTPUT is completely dependent upon the font used.  You have to use a fixed width font like `Courier New` for the OUTPUT to appear lined up.

Comment: string.Format works exactly the same. I need same width on screen in pixels. Thanks for quick response though.

Comment: @ChrisLively - I've been looking for the type of font that needs to be used to actually add something new not mentioned in comments (I.e not sans serif)

Comment: @Pankaj If you're not using a fixed-width font you'll need something like Graphics.MeasureString() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) and then try to pad out appropriately. Problably easiest to switch to a fixed-width font.

Comment: @Sayse: It is perfectly acceptable on SO to combine your answer with information given in either comments or other answers in order to form a complete answer for the question.  You don't need to purposely pick something else..

Comment: @ChrisLively - Personally I feel this detracts from the voting system, if I agree with an answer then I'd rather vote an existing answer. I am also against taking credit for other peoples ideas, As I said in previous comment I was looking for what evan mentioned

Comment: @Sayse: you might want to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35211/adding-someone-elses-answer-to-your-own-to-make-a-better-answer/35215#35215  A complete answer is much better than a partial one; the goal of the voting is to locate the *best* answer.  In part, this means the most complete one.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I am never satisfied by monospaced fonts, so I use character padding with a micro-space character (about 1 pixel wide) (char)0x200A to line things up.  This is especially useful when simulating column alignment with a list of strings.  The most flexible method is to use a while loop comparing string pixel widths and adding the space character until the match.  I use System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText() with a NoPadding flag and just to be save, an initial size of int.MaxValue, then check the Width parameter of System.Drawing.Size.  If you feed in any Font in the MeasureText constructor, it works with any font.